# Delete Query in MySQL 5.7 not working because error SQL Error [1093] shown

Tags: mysql

I tried to see other similar problems and i've done the same as other people but my delete clause is not working.

```
    DELETE gl FROM int_id2_game_server.game_link gl
    WHERE gl.game_pack_id = 794 AND gl.id NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT parent_id FROM int_id2_game_server.game_link
    WHERE gl2.game_pack_id = 794 AND gl2.parent_id IS NOT NULL)gltemp);
```

Error shown as SQL Error [1093] [HY000]: You can't specify target table 'gl' for update in FROM clause

Which modification I have to do?

Comment: On the first line you aske MySQL to delete the table `gl` because (I believe) you tried to give it the alias `gl`, but forgot to put an `as` before the name. It suppose to look like this `DELETE gl FROM int_id2_game_server.game_link as gl` but it will still fail, because you're still trying to delete the **`gl` TABLE**. If it is a field, rename the alias to somethign else

Comment: as the mysql delete query syntax is `DELETE FROM table`. remove gl which is after `delete`

Comment: @Karnal-YK this means to another error, maybe is possible in newer versions but not in 5.7 Mysql

Comment: @kmp thanks, but that is not working. you need to use the same alias as the table. you don't delete all the table, because the where clause specifies what has to be deleted. the problem is that when using subqueries it's not working, without subqueries I can delete like my example